# Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am doing a Obj-C to Swift Conversion, and am hitting a roadblock. I am getting the error 'Missing argument for parameter #1 in call' after  calling

```
self.tabataTimerUpdated() //error
```

This function that is being called (which I converted to swift) is:

```
func tabataTimerUpdated(NSNotification) {

    self.showTime()

}
```

Here is what it looks like in it's original Obj-C form:

```
- (void)tabataTimerUpdated:(NSNotification *)notification {
[self showTime];
}
```

Where did I go wrong in the conversion, and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Where is the `notification` parameter in the Swift code?

Comment: I don't know where/how it fits in, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you have

```
func tabataTimerUpdated(NSNotification) {
}
```

try remove NSNotification, look like this:

```
func tabataTimerUpdated() {
}
```

or specify something in there, like this:

```
func tabataTimerUpdated(notification: NSNotification){
}
```

and when you call the function, use:

```
self.tabataTimerUpdated(yourNotificationVariableInHere)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I'm going crazy or just blanking, but what would be my notification variable in this particular instance?

Comment: What is your notificationVariable in object-C?

- (void)tabataTimerUpdated:(NSNotification *)notification {
[self showTime];
}

if you don't have any, simply use 
func tabataTimerUpdated() {
}

Comment: Try put nothing inside the bracket first and call the function like this:
self.tabataTimerUpdated()
 compile to see if it runs

Comment: Hmm, simply leaving it without the NSNotification function still leads the app to crashing.

Comment: How did you call the function in objective-C?

Comment: func tabataTimerUpdated() {}

Comment: ... So I added (notification) to the function... and it works. You know, some people work better at night, turns out I'm not one of them...